# scale of one predictor affects significance of another

Tags: multiple-regression, scales

I have often read that predictors can or should be transformed to ease interpretation of the slope or intercept, or to standardize the coefficients. With this in mind, I attempted to rescale year in a data set, and met with unexpected behavior.

The following reproducible example stemmed from data including a year effect and many factor levels (it's actually count data, but the behavior is apparently not dependent on the family of the distribution).

```r
    set.seed(1)
    
    ex <- data.frame(year = rep(2003:2013,each=16))
    ex$season <- rep(0:1,length(ex$year)/2)
    ex$level <- rep(1:4,length(ex$year)/4)
    
    ex$year.min <- with(ex, year-min(year))
    
    ex$abund <- with(ex, 0.4*year + 0.15*season + 0.1*level +
      -0.15*year*season - 0.8*season*level + 0.1*year*level +
      rnorm(length(year)) )
        
    form.year <- abund ~ year + season + level + year:season + 
                   year:level + season:level
    form.year.min <- abund ~ year.min + season + level + 
                year.min:season + year.min:level + season:level
    
    lm.year <- lm(form.year, data=ex)
    lm.year.min <- lm(form.year.min, data=ex)
    
    summary(lm.year)
    summary(lm.year.min)
```

Can someone explain what is going on? If rescaling alters main effects, how does one choose a predictor scale? It's suspicious to me that the interaction coefficients are unaffected, and if they are omitted, then the transformation does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `year.min` is not a scaled version of `year`, it is a shifted version of it. Changing this in the regression will change the intercept and, therefore, all the main effects.

Second, when I run your code, the first thing I noticed about the summaries is that $R^2 = 1$. That surely indicates overfitting.

Third, it's pretty clear that there is a lot of collinearity in your model. abund is a linear function of the other variables. Collinearity can play havoc with p values and coefficient estimates. I checked the condition indexes and there are several that are in the thousands.